# Direct sum of reals and quaternions is not a semigroup algebra for some semigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra, semigroups

For a given semigroup $S$, the [semigroup algebra](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Semi-group_algebra) over some field $F$ is the set of formal sum with the convolution product, and is denoted by $F[S]$.

If we built the direct sum
$$
 \mathbb R \oplus \mathbb H
$$
of the two $\mathbb R$-algebras, with $\mathbb R \cdot \mathbb H = 0$, why is this not isomorphic to $\mathbb R[S]$ for some semigroup $S$.

Any hints how to show this?

I looked at other examples, like $\mathbb R \oplus \mathbb R \cong \mathbb R[S]$ with $S = \{ 1', 1 + 1' \}$ where $1'$ is the unit in the second direct summand. But I fail to find an argument that the above direct sum $\mathbb R \oplus \mathbb H$ is not of this form.

Comment: I'm a bit hampered by not knowing how *semigroup* algebras behave, but I know a thing or two about group rings. It also seems to complicate things if you want to allow *any* field $k$ such that $k[S]=\mathbb R\times \mathbb H$.  If the problem was about $\mathbb R[S]$, then there are a few handholds.

Comment: If you knew it was $\mathbb R[S]$ and $\mathbb R$-algebra isomorphisms, then you'd know you're looking at semigroups with five elements. It took me surprisingly a long time to find a reference saying there are over 1000 semigroups of order 5. I think though, since the ring has identity, it must be a monoid?  If I knew how many noncommutative semigroups/monoids of order 5 exist, I would be further along to understanding the problem.

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb R \oplus \mathbb H$ has a unit, the sum of the units from both summands. So you suggest the only way is to "brute-force"-like enumerate all cases of semigroups with five elements...

Comment: That's the first thing that came to mind, considering the noncommutativity of $\mathbb H$.  But I could be missing something slick that is just structural.  The problem is I don't know how well-behaved the structure theory is for monoid rings as compared to group rings.  See, if it were a group, I would just say "look: the group has to be abelian since it has five elements, and so the group ring is commutative. you can't have $\mathbb H$ as a factor." All of that would be called into question if some complicated, noncommutative monoids of order 5 exist.

Comment: Or if you were allowed to use some subfield of $\mathbb R$ as the coefficient ring.

Comment: I wonder what the version of the characterization of semisimple group rings looks like for semigroup rings... if it exists.